# C#: byte 0 does not get recognized as null value

Tags: c#, iis

i'm sending data via a post-request to my IIS. Everything is working fine, but now I realizied that I cannot send null values to the IIS. No matter what I try, the respond data is not recognized as a null.

Here is the post-data sniffed with wireshark:

```
Encapsulated multipart part: 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="@Beschreibung"\n\r\n
Data (1 byte)
Data: 00
[Length: 1]
Boundary: \r\n--*****\r\n
```

And here my code that is inside my IIS webmethod:

```
            HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;

            var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postedContext.Request.Form["@Beschreibung"]);

            var beschreibung = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            log.Info("BYTE ARRAY START");
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                log.Info(b);
            }
            log.Info("BYTE ARRAY ENDE");

            log.Info("Beschreibung: |" + beschreibung + "|");
            if (beschreibung == null)
                log.Info("IST NULL");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(beschreibung))
                log.Info("IST NULL OR EMPTY");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(beschreibung))
                log.Info("IST NULL OR WHITESPACE");
```

And the log output:

```
2018-07-31 10:59:09,826 [24] INFO - BYTE ARRAY START
2018-07-31 10:59:09,826 [24] INFO - 0
2018-07-31 10:59:09,826 [24] INFO - BYTE ARRAY ENDE
2018-07-31 10:59:09,826 [24] INFO - Beschreibung: | |
```

As you can see, the data in whireshark is only one byte and that is 0. The bytearray representation of the data in the C# code inside my webmethod is still only one byte that is 0.
BUT the string itself is not null, nor an empty string, it is not even a whitespace, because the code doesn't run into a single of the if-statements.

What am I missing here? I need to recognize this string as a null, so I can write DBNull.Value inside my database and not " " or "".

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit:
Okay, understood. Null is a valid char...
Here is the sending site (in Xamarin.iOS), I might better start a new topic and ask the Xamarin guys how to send null.

```
var postBody = new NSMutableData();
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd).Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"@Beschreibung\"" + crlf).Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString(lineEnd).Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString("\0").Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString(lineEnd).Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
        postBody.AppendData(new NSString(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd).Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
```

In line 5 I send the data as "\0". 
Earlier I sent it with

```
byte zero = 0;
postbody.AppendBytes(new byte[]{zero};
```

So to only send a byte 0, but that's of course the same problem...

Comment: You might be better off posting your data as JSON or some such.

Comment: The null *character*, represented by code point 0, is a perfectly valid character to find contained in a `string`. You're sending a string containing just that one character and that's what your code has received. Such a string is *not* the same as a `null` reference, and I don't think it's considered to be whitespace.

Comment: So the problem would appear to be on the *sending* side when it's sending a string containing a null character when you *want* it to send an empty string. Since we've no idea what the sending side looks like, we won't be able to offer suggestions for *fixing* it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because the sting is not null nor empty. It contains a single char ('\0')

Null ('\0') is a perfectly OK character thus this behaviour is correct.

You might test for it by comparing your string with `beschreibung == "\0"`

Thomas

Comment: Hmm, I do send the data as new NSString("\0").Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8) but I thought that this would then be recognized as null later on. Is there any chance to send a "real" null? If not I will use your comparison. Thanks.

Comment: @Tobe - you appear to be applying a [tag:c] convention (that strings are terminated by a null character) and applying it in other situations. I cannot talk for NSString but certainly C# strings can *contain* null characters, which C "strings" cannot. I wouldn't be very surprised if `new NSString("")` gave you an *actual* empty string in that environment (Objective C?). It certainly seems from the code you've shown that an NSString is also capable of containing null characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an empty string - send an empty string:

```
postBody.AppendData(new NSString("").Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8));
```

As I said in another comment, "strings are arrays of characters terminated by a null character" is a (feature/mistake) of [c](/questions/tagged/c) and *most* more recent languages recognize that a null character is perfectly valid *within* a string.

Comment: I don't want to send an empty string. I want to send a null object, so that the database entry will be DBNull and not "", which in some cases is a big difference in my database.

Comment: Okay, so the real problem is, there's no such things as a "null string". In C#, for instance, you either have a *reference* to a string or you have a null *reference*. The normal convention with posting form data is, if I remember correctly, to *not specify the parameter/value combination at all*. You'd then determine that by *checking* whether `@Beschreibung` exists in the form data before trying to access its value.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will probably just check with beschreibung == "\0" for now. It is not very possible that a user manages to enter that somewhere in a textbox or something else so that should do the trick :-)